# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String' in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, dateformatter

I have a method like this.

```
func getFirstDayX(date:Date)->CGFloat
{
   // let date = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat  = "EEEE"//"EE" to get short style
    guard let dayInWeek = dateFormatter.string(from: (date as? Date)!) else
    {
        return 0.0
    }//"Sunday"
    let dayX:CGFloat!
    print("day in week-------\(dayInWeek)")
    switch dayInWeek {
    case "Monday":
        dayX=0.0
    case "Tuesday":
        dayX=lblDayName.frame.size.width
    case "Wednesday":
        dayX=lblDayName.frame.size.width*2
    case "Thursday":
        dayX=lblDayName.frame.size.width*3
    case "Friday":
        dayX=lblDayName.frame.size.width*4
    case "Saturday":
        dayX=lblDayName.frame.size.width*5
    case "Sunday":
        dayX=lblDayName.frame.size.width*6
    default:
        dayX=0.0
    }

    return dayX
}
```

But I am getting an error as

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
>   'String'

What would be the reason for this? Please help me.

**UPDATE**

this is the way it was before I add the locale and guard condition. Kindly check this.

```
func getFirstDayX(date:Date)->CGFloat
{

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat  = "EEEE"//"EE" to get short style
 let dayInWeek = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date) else

let dayX:CGFloat!
print("day in week-------\(dayInWeek)")
switch dayInWeek {
case "Monday":
    dayX=0.0
case "Tuesday":
    dayX=lblDayName.frame.size.width
case "Wednesday":
    dayX=lblDayName.frame.size.width*2
case "Thursday":
    dayX=lblDayName.frame.size.width*3
case "Friday":
    dayX=lblDayName.frame.size.width*4
case "Saturday":
    dayX=lblDayName.frame.size.width*5
case "Sunday":
    dayX=lblDayName.frame.size.width*6
default:
    dayX=0.0
}

return dayX
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Two mistakes:

> guard let dayInWeek = dateFormatter.string(from: (date as? Date)!) else

1. `string(from:` date returns always an non-optional. Optional binding can be used only for optionals
2. You pass a non-optional `Date` so downcast to an optional `Date` and unwrap it immediately is <strike>ridiculous</strike> redundant.

Just write:

```
    let dayInWeek = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I suspect this crash and set that guard condition after I saw a crash report. I am suspecting it was due to not setting thelocale for the dateformatter. Because I havent set it previously. How can I set the locale to work the app for any locale setting on a device?

Answer (score 2):

Your bug has been explained in other answers. However, let me propose a simpler solution because using the name of the day to get the index is just <del>silly</del> too complicated. You don't need a date formatter at all, simply ask directly for the weekday!

```
func getFirstDayX(date: Date) -> CGFloat {
    // Sunday = 0, Monday = 1 ... Saturday = 6
    let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: date)
    // Monday = 0, Tuesday = 1, ... Sunday = 7
    let weekdayIndex = (weekday + 6) % 7

    return lblDayName.frame.size.width * weekdayIndex
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### guard let ...

When you write

```
guard let dayInWeek = [OPTIONAL_EXPRESSION] else { return 0.0 }
```

The **[OPTIONAL_EXPRESSION]** should be an expression with returns an optional value.

But in your case you did write

```
dateFormatter.string(from: (date as? Date)!)
```

which always returns a `String`.

So there's no need to use the `guard let` construct.

> And there is no need to write `(date as? Date)!` neither

### Solution

Simply write

```
let dayInWeek = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I havent add the guard condition before. I got a crashed log from a user in this method. And I havent set any locale to the date formatter. So I am suspecting this crash is due to not setting the locale to date formatter. Is it ok to set this locale? how should I set the locale to work the app on any locale setting?

Comment: @user1960169 So this is not the code that does generate the crash?

Comment: no,, when crash happened I was not added that guard condition. Also I havent set the locale as well. But thanks for showing me this issue. It really helped me to reduce the complexity of this problem.

Comment: @user1960169 Well if we don't have the real code that generates the crash, helping is very difficult :)

Comment: Please check my Updated part.